# How to fix product thumb image size in Open cart?

Tags: php, css, opencart, image-size

I got a problem, I tried several times but I couldn't find a solution for this. 
As you know, we can change product image size in System / Setting / Image, but it won't set to the size of product page. let me show you what I mean, Please check this image:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/t7AGqCL.jpg]

The exact size of Product Image Thumb Size is 770 x 228

So, even if we will set the same size in System/Setting/Image , it won't be fit perfectly and then we will face problem in responsive / mobile  view...

[image: http://i.imgur.com/XmN3ha9.jpg]

Here is also mobile view:

so how can I set image size to be fit in width and height, maybe with css or java script ?
Here is the code for this specific section

```
<li><a class="France" href="<?php echo $popup; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" /></a></li>
```

in the root of:

```
catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl
```

I really appreciate for any information and share your knowledge about it.

Thanks and cheers

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED!   thanks to HarnishDesign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, missing thumbnail css class according to OpenCart html css structure. So, You need to add `thumbnail` css class in `<a>` tag. Try following code & then check it.

```
<li><a class="France thumbnail" href="<?php echo $popup; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" /></a></li>
```